# How can I get my laptop's internal speakers to work correctly on NixOS?

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, alsa, nixos

As far as I can tell, the subwoofers on my Lenovo Yoga C930 aren't being engaged at all on NixOS, which results in a really flat sound. The speakers sound great when I reboot into Windows 10. How can I configure NixOS so that I can get these speakers to work fully?

This is what I think is the relevant output from `lspci -v`:

```
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3831
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 146
    Memory at 2ffb018000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 2ffb000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl
```

Edit: here's the output of aplay -l:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC298 Analog [ALC298 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Edit: [and here's the output of `alsa-info.sh`](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=596b5dcb8c2e95ef4cd64b800f1be1a082a7d4f6).

Edit: Here's what I'm seeing in hdajackretask: [image: hda-jack-retask screenshot]

Edit: And here are some errors I've been getting: [image: errors]

Hdajackretask creates a script in `/tmp` that I can run with sudo just fine, but then I don't think changes take effect.

So the problem is not really that I don't have `tee` installed (I do; hdajackretask just can't see it), it's that I don't know the right settings (pins, functions, etc) to set it to, *and* I don't know how to get the actual changes to take effect on NixOS.

Comment: I would look into enabling alsa-source on NixOS. From what I have seen that should work.

Comment: What's the output of `aplay -l`? Are the speakers unmuted in `alsamixer`?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa, I just updated by question with the output of that command. And yep, I checked `alsamixer`, and there are two outputs listed (besides all the S/PDIF, Headphones, "beep" etc): "speaker" and "PCM." Both are unmuted and set at a reasonable volume.

Comment: @MichaelProkopec, I can't find an option or a package with the name alsa-source, or anything like it. How can I do that?

Comment: NixOS is vary limited on what it has in its repo's. You will probably have to build it from source.

Comment: How does that work?

Comment: The by-far best invention there is if you seek audio-related help on Linux is [alsa-info.sh](http://alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Help_To_Debug) - Run the script, add the link it gives you to your question.

Comment: @confetti, I just updated my answer with the output of that script.

Comment: Can you get a hold of pavucontrol?

Comment: I have pavucontrol, but there is no setting there for subwoofers.

Comment: can you tell the output of `pulseaudio -vvv` (you can use https://pastebin.com/)

Comment: @sanjeev, sure: https://hastebin.com/vekuvazado.makefile Although I think it's more of an alsa problem than a pulseaudio problem.

Comment: Try using a live USB version of a mainstream Linux distribution and see if audio works as intended. If it does, get run alsa-info.sh again. the information from there can be compared to information from installed OS

Comment: I tried using a live USB of the latest Ubuntu, but it has the same problem.

Comment: at first kill the pulse audio `pulseaudio --kill` then try to see the error inside`pulseaudio -vvv`... sorry for this late reply.